# "If a man write a better book, preach a better sermon..."

Tags: grammaticality, conditionals, subjunctive-mood, early-modern-english, protasis

There is an old quotation attributed to Ralph Waldo Emerson:

> If a man *write* a better book, *preach* a better sermon, or *make* a better mouse-trap than his neighbour, tho' he build his house in the woods, the world will make a beaten path to his door.

Why are the verbs in the conditional clause in the infinitive, instead of third person singular? Old usage? Subjunctive? Neither?

Comment: Present subjunctive.

Comment: As for why Emerson chose to use that diction instead of the more contemporary "If a man were to write a better book..." I think he wanted to echo the stately, authoritative tone of the King James Bible, which abounds in sentences of the type—e.g., "If a man say, I love God, and hateth his brother, he is a liar" [_First Epistle of John_ iv 20] and "If any man among you seem to be religious, and bridleth not his tongue, but deceiveth his own heart, this man's religion is vain" _Epistle of James_ i 26]. The King James version influenced many 19th-century writers' notions of literary gravitas.

Comment: @SvenYargs You may be right about echoing the KJV, but he did it because the consequent was in the *will*-future not the *would*-conditional. In earlier forms of English, that meant that the *if*-part had to be in the present subjunctive.  Long, long ago *“If a man be ready for it, he will leave peacefully”* contrasted with *“If a man were ready for it, he would leave peacefully”*.

Comment: @tchrist: One difference I belatedly recognize between the two Bible quotations I gave and the quotation from Emerson is that both of the former have the form "If a man do X, he [or his religion] **is** Y," while the latter has the form "If a man do X, the world **will do** Z." Does "will do," with its future-directed aspect, attach to the present subjunctive as satisfactorily as "is," with its current-existence aspect, does; or ought Emerson to have framed the last part of his sentence as "the world makes a beaten path to his door"? My command of tense analysis is very weak, as you can tell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If a man *write* a better book, *preach* a better sermon, or *make* a better mouse-trap than his neighbour, tho' he *build* his house in the woods, the world **will** make a beaten path to his door.

It is the subjunctive used in older writings, of the type (pointed out by @tchrist) *if A* **be** X, *then A* **will** (the key here being the **will future** instead of **would**).

Similar to almost anything you read in the KJB:

> Or if a soul *swear*, pronouncing with his lips to do evil, or to do good, whatsoever it *be* that a man shall pronounce with an oath, and it *be* hid from him; when he knoweth of it, then he **shall** be guilty in one of these.

Comment: *“If A **be** X, then A **will** whatever”* is the old way, and it is **not** a hypothetical. *“If A **were** X, then A **would** whatever”* is the hypothetical version. See the difference? We now use present indicative instead of present subjunctive in the first case. So, too, does Spanish, which often confuses learners. But regular *if*-clauses in the present are (now, but not aforetimes) cast in the indicative mood in **both** languages, reserving the past subjunctive for only when there is an actual conditional following, meaning modal *would* in English or an *-ía* inflexion in Spanish.

Comment: @tchrist - I follow up to a point, but... is it not irrealis? It is indicative subjunctive?

Comment: When the *then* side takes a *will*, the *if* side takes present, be it present indicative as we now use or present subjunctive as was once (more :) common. The “irrealis” thing you are talking about where we are hypothesizing about a counterfactual reality uses backshifting, which is where the *“were...would”* sequence comes into play. But saying *“If she **is** ready, we **will** go now”* does not involve anything unreal, neither now nor back when it was once phrased *“If she **be** ready, we **shall** go now.”*  Only *“If she **were** ready, we **would** go now”* involves unreality.

Comment: Those are simple forms, and adding in a perfective aspect doesn’t change the unreality bit.  So the past-perfect also involves unreality: *“If only she **had been** ready, we **would have** gone then.”* Making it a perfect form is tougher in the present, I suppose, but it is still not unreal: *“If I **have been** less than direct with you, it **has been** for none but the very best of reasons, my lady.”*  That version doesn’t even take a *will have been* in the consequent, though. In any event, it is still not unreal. English has so many conditionals that what ESLer are taught is a tragedy.

Comment: As the old tongue twister has it. *Whether the weather **be fine**, or whether the weather **be not**; we'll weather the weather, whatever the weather, whether we like it or not*

Comment: @tchrist “If I have been less than direct with you, it has been for none but the very best of reasons, my lady.” imho, this is not a condition/consequence clause example. That's why the second clause (explanatory) doesn't take a "will". Am I wrong?

Comment: @user463240 There’s a present–present pair in the non-perfective for that one, too, such as *“If you’re pregnant, then I’m a monkey’s uncle.”*  I don’t know how how else you could classify these sentences but calling them condition–consequent ones.  They just march to the beat of a different drummer as far as as tense match-ups go.

Answer (score 2):

To complement medica's answer, and because I love trivia, I offer the following.

The original quote (in the OP's question) now updated is

> Build a better mousetrap, and they will beat a path to your door

the popular advice is attributed to Ralph Waldo Emerson, but it was in 1889 that Sarah Yule included it in her book (p. 138 ), *Borrowings*, seven years *after* Emerson's death in April 27, 1882. In 1912 Yule stated she had copied it from a lecture delivered by the eminent American essayist in 1871.  But there is no proof that he actually wrote those lines using the present subjunctive. A considerably longer version exists in Emerson's journal entry dated 1855

> I trust a good deal to common fame, as we all must. **If a man has** good
>   corn, or wood, or boards, or pigs, to sell, or can make better chairs
>   or knives, crucibles or church organs, than anybody else, **you will
>   find** a broad hard-beaten road to his house.

Note that Emerson used the present indicative in this instance.

---

<sup>sources: [What They Didn't Say: A Book of Misquotations](http://books.google.it/books?id=jxFQqDLav6wC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q=write%20a%20better%20book%20make%20a%20better%20mousetrap&f=false) by Elizabeth Knowles. [Bartleby.com](http://www.bartleby.com/73/1780.html) and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_a_better_mousetrap,_and_the_world_will_beat_a_path_to_your_door)</sup>

Comment: ..... wow!!! +1